# Google Fit api BLE connect issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-fit, android-ble, google-fit-sdk

I want to connect Mi Band 3 with my application through Google Fit SDK. I am facing issue to connect band through bluetooh. as given in [Offical Google Fit Documentation - BLE Sensor](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/ble-sensors) I am using following code in Kotlin

```
 var bleScanCallbacks: BleScanCallback = object : BleScanCallback() {
        override fun onDeviceFound(device: BleDevice?) {
            // A device that provides the requested data types is available
        }

        override fun onScanStopped() {
            // The scan timed out or was interrupted
        }
    }

    var response: Task<Void> = Fitness.getBleClient(
        this,
        GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!
    )
        .startBleScan(
            Arrays.asList(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA),
            1000, bleScanCallbacks
        )
```

but it showing that

> 'getBleClient(Activity, GoogleSignInAccount): BleClient!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

and

> 'BleScanCallback' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

It suggesting to use BluetoothManager. I am beginner in android development. Java solution will also work.

Comment: If you are targeting Android 8.0+, you should consider using Companion Device Pairing API to pair your device. For more infos: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing

Comment: Thanks @matdev, but at this moment I connected my band directly but facing issue to connect it with Google Fit, but this will help me in upcoming modules.

Comment: well a method being deprecated does not mean it does not work. What is your issue apart from this message ?

Comment: I tried using that, but I am not getting accurate data as well as I required data frequently, but it is read data from sensors only once.

Comment: Does your app actually need to connect to the Mi Band to read the info you need or scanning its advertisement data is enough ? If advertisement data are enough, have you tried scanning continuously ?

Comment: Yes yes, I want to connect to mi band. I am from python background so I am beginner in app development. Can you suggest how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

After the BLE scanner has found your device, you can connect to its GATT server.

To connect to a GATT server on a BLE device, you use the `connectGatt()` method. This method takes three parameters: a `Context` object, `autoConnect` (boolean indicating whether to automatically connect to the BLE device as soon as it becomes available), and a reference to a `BluetoothGattCallback`:

```
BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
```

This connects to the GATT server hosted by the BLE device, and returns a BluetoothGatt instance, which you can then use to conduct GATT client operations such as discovering services, reading and writing on BLE characteristics.

For a `BluetoothGattCallback` sample code and other infos:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le